# Nested for loops in Batch. An error has arisen, but unsure why

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops

My script calls information from a 'settings.txt' file of the form

> property1=value11,value12,...,value1n 
>   property2=value21,value22,...,value2n 
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   propertym=valuem1,valuem2,...,valuemn

in order to add 'n' schemas to the database, using a file 'setup.txt' of the form

> 2 
>   3 
>   . 
>   . 
>   . 
>   n+1

to specify which schema is being added. The 'for' loop that loops through each schema is

```
FOR /F %%T IN (setup.txt) DO ( 
    SET position=%%T        
    FOR /F "tokens=1,!position!, delims==," %%A IN (settings.txt) DO (
        IF "%%A"=="property1" (
            SET %%A="%%B"
        )
[The code then continues to go through capturing the rest of the variables, and
then executes the relevant SQL commands]
```

The error message that I get from this is

> ( was unexpected at this time.

The script previously worked with only one schema at a time (before I added the two for loops), so the problem is either with how I've set out the for loops, or some conflict with the for loops and the previous code. All that I have added to the previously working script is the two FOR statements, and the SET statement.

I've had a few people look over it, and none of them have been able to find the problem. Any ideas here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,!position!, ...
```

You can't use delayed expansion in the FOR/f options, as the FOR command has it's own parser and it can't expand options this way.

But you can move it to a function and use percent expansion

```
FOR /F %%T IN (setup.txt) DO ( 
    call :myFunc %%T
)
:exit /b

:myFunc
FOR /F "tokens=1,%1, delims==," %%A IN (settings.txt) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="property1" (
        SET %%A="%%B"
    )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks. I'm relatively new to coding, so haven't encountered calling of functions yet. I'll be sure to check it out. Thanks once again.